# How to start with Magento 2 ? for newbs in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, database, admin, installation

I really know this might be off-topic, but I already, "red" the https://magento.com/
https://devdocs.magento.com/

I just have started in a company with 50+ employees and most of them are even greater newbs from me.
They have a website ran on Magento2 and, it is just those little country from the Balkaines that don't know much English. So here is the deal. They want me to support the website and also to make modifications, backups all the things. New to Magento2. And the boss wants to make just a new Magento2 website for another brand of his products.

So just where to start? Like A,B,C

How to choose hosting, how to install Magento2, how to choose theme, how to modify it if the boss says I don't like this. Just something for total newbs, cause from the magento.com I'm even more confused then from the start, without knowing a thing. I mean what is CRON for example ? Why I just can't make the Magento2 installation for 10 minutes, like the famous WordPress 5 mins install? Things like that.
And pls, I beg you show me a working guide, cause I already failed in a migration from one server 2 another, and also failed in installing a new Magento2 installation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Magento 2 documentation is your best friend, and also Magento stack exchange in some cases, if ever you can't find answers to your questions, you can ask them here and we'll try to help you.

Comment: Thank you dude :)

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to look into good quality managed server hosting and then to follow the official Magento 2 installation documentation. You will need command-line access at some points too.

If you're inexperienced at Magento you will find it a struggle to quickly get to grips if you're used to the ease of use of WordPress. Also get good at Googling, biggest thing that helped me. Good luck.